# How to hide parent if children are hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:** I need a way in jQuery to hide a parent div if all the children in a list contained within said div are hidden.

**Context:** I'm working on an employee portal that allows an admin to upload PDFs. When they upload the PDF, they can attach it to a category and they can also add tags to it. The purpose of the tags is for an inline filtering feature that will only show files associated with a particular tag if they select it from the menu. A simplified example of my markup:

```
<!-- Filtering Menu -->
<ul class="resource-filters">
    <li class="all">All</li>
    <li class="filter-example">Filter #1</li>
    <li class="filter-example">Filter #2</li>
    <li class="filter-example">Filter #3</li>
</ul>

<!-- Category #1 -->
<div class="resources-files-container">
    <h3>Category #1</h3>

    <ul class="attachment-list">
        <li class="filter-example-1">
            <a href="#">PDF Example #1</a>
        </li>

        <li class="filter-example-3">
            <a href="#">PDF Example #3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>  

<!-- Category #2 -->
<div class="resources-files-container">
    <h3>Category #2</h3>

    <ul class="attachment-list">
        <li class="filter-example-2 hidden">
            <a href="#">PDF Example #2</a>
        </li>

        <li class="filter-example-2 hidden">
            <a href="#">PDF Example #2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is, say I select "Filter #1" from the menu. All list items that don't have the class of `.filter-example-1` will be set to `display: none` (the hidden class). In the example markup above, that would mean that Category #2 now has zero items to show. I want the entire div of `.resources-files-container` to hide (until they select another filter that is appropriate).

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of hours now and have done plenty of searching (I've found some solutions that fit part of my criteria, but not this specific case). I've got the entire app figured out except for this particular portion. The following jQuery isn't particularly relevant for this specific problem I'm having, but just to give you some context:

```
// only run if we're in the portal
if ($("#portal-container").length) { 

  // get the unique list of classnames
  var classes = {};
  $('.attachment-list li').each(function() {
      $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() { 
          if (this !== '') {
              classes[this] = this;
          }    
      });
  });


  //build the list items
  class_list = '';
  for (class_name in classes) {
      class_list += '<li class="'+class_name+'">'+class_name+'</li>';
  };


  // append the resulting list to the page
  $(class_list).appendTo('#resource-filter ul');


  // sorting functionality
  $('#portal-page').on('click', '#resource-filter li', function() {
    // set the current filter
    var filterVal = $(this).attr('class');

    // add current state to filter button
    $('#resource-filter li.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    // filtering function
    if(filterVal == 'filter-all') {
        $('.attachment-list li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('.attachment-list li').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }

  });
}
```

I highly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".resources-files-container")
    .filter(function(){
        return $(this).find("li:visible").length == 0;
    })
    .hide();
```

Filter the list of `.resources-files-container` elements to just those with no visible `li` elements and then hide that filtered set.

http://jsfiddle.net/n403agxn/

Comment: This does exactly what I need in the fiddle, but not working plug-and-play into my script. This is a good starting point though, thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

Also include an else to toggle the visibility back on if the selection is changed:

```
function toggleContainersByChildren() {
    $('.resources-files-container').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('li:visible').length === 0) { // note the three = signs
            $(this).hide(); //hides the container if no children are visible
        } else {
            $(this).show(); //shows it again if the children are turned back on
        }
    });
}

toggleContainersByChildren(); //call this function to check your containers for visible children every time the filter is changed
```

Edit: Calling attention to the === equality sign...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if all the `li` inside a div `.resources-files-container` don't have the `.filter-example-1` class...

So, it would be something like this:

```
//Select all div with this class, and iterate through them
$('.resources-files-container').each(function() {

    //Checks if the number of li's with the specified class inside this div is "0"
    if($(this).find('li.filter-example-1').length == 0) {

        //Hides the div, because there's no visible li in it.
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```