# How to hide multiple elements based on visibility state of other similarly named elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Problem**: I want to hide multiple elements based on if the child elements of similarly named elements are showing or not.

**Context**: I have multiple list items contained within one div like so:

```
<div class="itemGrid">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <button class="header" id="headerCommonItems">
            "Common Items"
            ::after
         </button>
         <ul class="icons" id="iconsCommonItems">
            <li class="itemTile">Apples</li>
            <li class="itemTile">Oranges</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <button class="header" id="headerUncommonItems">
            "Uncommon Items"
            ::after
         </button>
         <ul class="icons" id="iconsUncommonItems">
            <li class="itemTile">Pears</li>
            <li class="itemTile">Bananas</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <button class="header" id="headerRareItems">
            "Rare Items"
            ::after
         </button>
         <ul class="icons" id="iconsRareItems">
            <li class="itemTile">Pineapples</li>
            <li class="itemTile">Guavas</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have a search feature that show/hides icons based on the search criteria (e.g. if I searched the term "common", it would only show the icons for Apples and Oranges, but hide all other icons).

I want to hide the headers if there are no corresponding icons that are visible. So using the previous example, I only want the "Common Items" header to show if I'm searching for the term "Common" and hide "Uncommon Items" and "Rare Items" headers. At the moment, it still would show the other headers even though there are no icons underneath.

I've tried referencing multiple SO pages, but this is my first time working with JQuery and I can't seem to get it to work. Here's a variation of what I've tried so far.

```
$.each($("[id ^= 'icons']").filter(
    function()
    {
        if ($(this).find('li:visible').length !== 0)
        {
            console.log("Visible children.");
            return;
        }
    }))
.hide();
```

I've been able to hide the icons, but I don't know how to reference the corresponding headers and hide those if the child elements of the icons are hidden.

Here are the other SO pages I've been referencing:

[Check if all children elements are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382353/check-if-all-children-elements-are-hidden)

[How to hide parent if children are hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732491/how-to-hide-parent-if-children-are-hidden/25732974)

Comment: Are the item children like pineapples and guava dynamically added/removed? From what I understand you just want to hide entire sections based on the search query?

Comment: Hi @Bren, yes, items like pineapples and guava are dynamically added/removed (more like hidden/unhidden). The search works by removing a class from all icons "visibleItem" and re-adds the "visibleItem" class back to the the icons that match the search criteria.

Comment: Are you looking for the ability to also search for terms like "apple" where it returns pineapple and apple since they are similarly named and both contain apple? When I say added/removed I'm referring to the elements actually being added and removed from the DOM, not CSS hiding it.

Comment: Hi, not the actual searching. Given your scenario, right now when I search "Apple", I already get "Apple" and "Pineapple" under their respective headers (Common Items for "Apple" and Rare Items for "Pineapple"). But what I'm also getting is a header for Uncommon Items with no items underneath it. I want to see if there are no items underneath Uncommon Items, then hide the header Uncommon Items as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly: "I want to hide the headers if there are no corresponding icons that are visible";

Just change your if logic to find hidden, not visible  `=== 0`, and then search for that elements siblings (`.header` is not a children of `ul class="icons"`):

```
$(this).siblings(".header").hide();
```

I also added to remove list icon:

```
$(this).parents("li").hide();
```

As you can see from example below, if both items in list `"Uncommon Items"` have class: `hidden`, it will remove all around it. If one is visible, it wont.

```js
$.each($("[id ^= 'icons']").filter(
    function() {
    
      $(this).siblings(".header").show();
      $(this).parents("li").show();
      
      if ($(this).find('li:visible').length === 0) {
        $(this).siblings(".header").hide();
        $(this).parents("li").hide();
        console.log("Hidden children.");
        return;
      }
    }))
  .hide();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemGrid">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button class="header" id="headerCommonItems">
            "Common Items"
            ::after
         </button>
      <ul class="icons" id="iconsCommonItems">
        <li class="itemTile">Apples</li>
        <li class="itemTile">Oranges</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="header" id="headerUncommonItems">
            "Uncommon Items"
            ::after
         </button>
      <ul class="icons" id="iconsUncommonItems">
        <li class="itemTile hidden">Pears</li>
        <li class="itemTile hidden">Bananas</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="header" id="headerRareItems">
            "Rare Items"
            ::after
         </button>
      <ul class="icons" id="iconsRareItems">
        <li class="itemTile">Pineapples</li>
        <li class="itemTile">Guavas</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

As requested add this out side of your `if` statement, it will always first show/reset all and then make new filtering in `if` statement.

```
  $(this).siblings(".header").show();
  $(this).parents("li").show();
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for! Which I'm running into a similar problem I believe. Is there a way for it to reset upon keystroke within the search bar? As right now, with the search term "apple", the Uncommon Headers disappears but remains gone even when the search bar is cleared.

Comment: @BryanTran I edited the post and snippet, this should fix that problem. But you are talking about search bars and keystrokes that I don't see,  if you are calling this function, this fix should do it.

Comment: @BryanTran If not, please make/edit question with  [mre] so I can see what is going on.

Comment: Your edits fixed it. Thank you very much for the help!